# Convert radio buttons to star ratings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have list of radio buttons that I am trying to convert to star ratings from this example http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating-demo-basic-usage

I've loaded all the dependencies and configured my code as the example but I've had no luck, any help with converting these radio buttons into a star rating would be appreciated!

```
<ul>
<li>
<div>
<div>Overall how was your experience?</div>
</div>
<div>
<div><input name="feedback_radio" type="radio" value="1" /> <label 
for="feedback_radio_1">1</label></div>
<div><input name="feedback_radio" type="radio" value="2" /> <label 
for="feedback_radio_2">2</label></div>
<div><input name="feedback_radio" type="radio" value="3" /> <label 
for="feedback_radio_3">3</label></div>
<div><input name="feedback_radio" type="radio" value="4" /> <label 
for="feedback_radio_4">4</label></div>
<div><input name="feedback_radio" type="radio" value="5" /> <label 
for="feedback_radio_5">5</label></div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

here is my fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/fn7rxums/

Comment: Style the radio buttons so they are horizontal, then change their image to stars. Then, program with a bit of js that tells the stars to be yellow of they are active, and blank if they aren't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the class of the input to "rating"

```
Automatically convert any input to a bootstrap star rating control by setting 
its class as rating. Note that the CSS class rating-loading when added, hides 
the input when the page is loading, and shows a plugin loading indicator until 
the widget is entirely loaded
```

taken directly from the website you linked.

```
<label for="feedback_radio_1">1</label>
<input name="feedback_radio" type="radio" value="1" class="rating" data-min="0" data-max="5" data-step="1"/>
```

Make sure you have the files installed and correctly included.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna use that plugin to implement the star rating, go follow their usage. There are much more dependencies you need cover. http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating#usage